# Jquery fixed div flickering

Tags: jquery

I have the code below:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
var h = jQuery('.container.section1').height();
var y = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
var rec_prev = jQuery("#recipe-prev");
var rec_next = jQuery("#recipe-next");
var pos_prev = rec_prev.offset().top + rec_prev.height();
var pos_next = rec_next.position();
var footer_pos = jQuery("#footer").offset().top;
var position = footer_pos - 200;
if( y > (h*.05) && y < (h*.8) ){
 jQuery("#recipe-prev").fadeIn("slow");
 jQuery("#recipe-next").fadeIn("slow");
} else {
foo_prev = footer_pos - pos_prev;

console.log(pos_prev);
if (foo_prev <= 5){
  rec_prev.css('position', 'absolute');
  rec_prev.css('top',position);
  rec_prev.css('height','195px');
  rec_next.css('position', 'absolute');
  rec_next.css('top',position);
  rec_next.css('height','195px');
 }
 else {
   rec_prev.css('position', 'fixed');
   rec_prev.css('top','auto');
   rec_next.css('position', 'fixed');
   rec_next.css('top','auto');
 }
}    
});
```

I want the 'recipe-prev' div to be sticky when he encounters the footer. The problem is that the div is starting flickering after it encounters the footer and I try to scroll. Do you have any idea what can I do?

Comment: Try to provide both the HTML and Javascript, or a working JSFiddle so we can better debug the problem with a live example.

Comment: It's a bit hard to give you the HTML because I use Drupal... but as I said, I have a small little box (on the left of the screen) that I want it to remain on the position before footer... after I scroll up it must go up, again.

Comment: Drupal doesn't use HTML? That's impressive for a web framework! But all sarcasm aside, it's going to be next to impossible to debug this issue without a working visual example... I can only guess at what you mean by "fixed div flickering"... Sorry.

Comment: Okey... so I tried to reproduce on JSFiddle. I want #myScrollspy to pin when it encounters the footer (and I don't want  to cover the footer). http://jsfiddle.net/r8c664hp/1/